# Axios post with Reactjs - Spring boot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Im very new with Axios, and im trying to do a POST request using Axios and my DB is not getting the data, it creates one entity and all the values are null except the primary key that is 0. Then, i get an error that i'm duplicating the primary key. I don't know if its not getting my JSON or if im doing something else wrong.

api.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const endpoints = {
 development: 'http://localhost:8080/',
};

export const api = axios.create({
baseURL: endpoints['development'],
timeout: 20000,
 headers: {"Content-type":"application/json" }
});
```

pacienteService.js

```
import { api } from './helpers/api.js';

const basePath = 'api';

let config = {
    headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    } 
}

function getAll() { return api.get(`${basePath}/pacientes`); }

function show(pacienteId) { return api.get(`${basePath}/?id=${pacienteId}`); }

function create(data) { return api.post(`${basePath}/pacientes`, data,config); }

const pacientesService = { getAll, show, create };
export default pacientesService;
```

Function that do the post when Submitting the form

```
handleSubmit(event){
    const paciente = {rut:this.state.rut,
    nombre:this.state.nombre ,
    nacionalidad:this.state.nombre ,
    sexo:this.state.nombre ,
    fecha_na:this.state.nombre ,
    domicilio:this.state.nombre ,
    diagnostico:this.state.nombre ,
    telefono:this.state.nombre ,
    gravedad:this.state.recuperacion
    }
      
       pacientesService.create({paciente}).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      })
}
```

Pd: I have printed all the states to see if they're correct, and they are.

Comment: what are the values logged by these two statements:

        `console.log(res);`

        `console.log(res.data);`

And also, what the server receives after you make the call?

Comment: res.data : {rut: 1, nombre: null, nacionalidad: null, sexo: null, fecha_na: null, …}

Comment: res : ```config:
baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/"
data: "{"paciente":{"rut":"20.080.354","nombre":"Cristóbal","nacionalidad":"Cristóbal","sexo":"Cristóbal","fecha_na":"Cristóbal","domicilio":"Cristóbal","diagnostico":"Cristóbal","telefono":"Cristóbal","gravedad":false}}
headers: {Content-Type: "application/json"}
maxContentLength: -1
method: "post"
transformRequest: [ƒ]
transformResponse: [ƒ]
url: "api/pacientes"
validateStatus: ƒ validateStatus(status)
data: {rut: 1, nombre: null, nacionalidad: null, sexo: null, fecha_na: null, …}
headers: {content-type: "application/json"}```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it passing data directly to `pacientesService.create()`.

From `pacientesService.create({paciente})`, to
`pacientesService.create({rut:this.state.rut,nombre:this.state.nombre,... })`